# What character set to use on GSM modem

Tags: c#, gsm, at-command

I have 2 GSM modems, the **K3772-Z** has its character set as 8859-1 and works fine.

But for my other GSM modem, its the **ZTE K3565-Z**, it wont work it keeps returning 
"Failed to set character set"

[image]

Does anyone know what character set to ue or is there a way for me to find out what character set use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix was to call `AT+CSCS=?`
That then returned "IRA","GSM","UCS2"